# Probability of detecting a defective bulb in exactly $n$ dependent trials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We have $5$ bulbs. Out of them exactly $1$ bulb is defective. It takes $1$ minute to check each bulb(assuming no delay between checks). The job is to detect the defective bulb.(We do not put back the bulbs back in the box after a checking)

> For some $1\leq x \leq 5$,
>
> a) find the probability that it takes exactly $x$ minute to detect the defective bulb.
> b) find the probability that it takes at most $x$ minute to detect the defective bulb.
> c) find the probability that it takes at least $x$ minute to detect the defective bulb

Here are the things that I tried.

Each trial depends on the previous trials. Thus, the probability is changing in each trial. Hence, we can write the probabilities in the following way(I hope the following are explanatory of my thoughts)
$$P(1)=\frac{1}{5}$$$$P(2)=\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{5}$$$$P(3)=\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{5}$$$$\vdots$$$$P(x)=\frac{1}{5}$$

> The constant nature of the probability is suspicious to me.

Then, I summed up the probabilities(Is this at all possible?) to get
$$P(\text{time}\leq x)=\sum_{n=1}^{x}P(x)=\frac{x}{5}$$ and $$P(\text{time}\geq x)=\sum_{n=x}^{5}P(x)=\frac{6-x}{5}$$

Is this approach correct or am I missing some detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the trial in the following manner: you first put all the bulbs in a row in some order, then check them one-by-one. The probability that the defective bulb is in each of the places is the same (symmetry), so you have a constant probability.

The rest is correct.